# Поворот пиксельного изображения. Разработка игр [Construct 3]

Tags: разработка-игр

Нужно чтобы при повороте угла обьекта, он пиксельно поворачивался как-бы в редакторе изображений, как это называется? (Construct 3)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]